# expose Btrfs snapshots with samba4 and vfs_shadow2

Tags: samba, btrfs, snapshot, fedora-22

I'm trying to implement the vfs_shadow2 module with samba 4.2 running on Fedora 22 to get windows explorer feature "previous versions" on clients to work.

The shared "folder" is an Btrfs subvolume in real, SELinux is enabled,
proper context has been set and the share is browsable, readable, writable for the user as expected. Also, I've created two snapshots as direct children of the share and named  them (as mentioned in the vfs_shadow_copy documentation [1]) like @GMT-YYYY.MM.DD-hh.mm.ss.

My smb.conf regarding that share is

```
[btrfs]
    comment = btrfs storagepool with subfolders, subvolumes and snapshots
    path = /srv/btrfs/subvol01
    vfs objects = shadow_copy2
    browseable = yes
    valid users = testuser
```

Nevertheless, when connecting with a Windows Client (Win 8.1 Professional x64) and trying to restore a file to a previous version I only get the hint that no previous versions could be found.

What am I missing? Is it an additional RPM-package that has to be installed (although I'v already installed everything containing samba of vfs in it's Name)? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Kind regards!

[1] https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages/vfs_shadow_copy2.8.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using this artikel: [[GUIDE] Windows Previous Versions and Samba (Btrfs - Atomic COW - Volume Shadow Copy)](http://forums.openmediavault.org/index.php/Thread/7331-GUIDE-Windows-Previous-Versions-and-Samba-Btrfs-Atomic-COW-Volume-Shadow-Copy/)

### How to reproduce a working configuration on Fedora22

**1) Create BTRFS subvolume**

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt #your BTRFS partition
btrfs subvolume create /mnt/share
brtfs subvolume create /mnt/share/.snapshots
umount /mnt
```

**2) edit fstab** (or mount manually according)

```
  
UUID={uuid_of_btrfs_partition} /share brtfs subvol=share 0 0
UUID={uuid_of_btrfs_partition} /share/.snapshots btrfs subvol=share/.snapshots 0 0
```

**3) Create Samba share**

```
[btrfs]  
    path = /share  
    vfs objects = shadow_copy2  
    shadow:format = @GMT_%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S  
    shadow:sort = desc  
    shadow:snapdir = .snapshots
```

**4) Create a readonly snapshot**

```
    brtfs subvolume snapshot -r /share /share/.snapshots/@GMT_`date +%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S`
```

**5) How to delete a snapshot**

```
btrfs subvolume delete /share/.snapshots/@GMT_2015.07.31-14.01.20
```